Save form data inside a user's profile in WooCommerce
I'm trying to save some data from a form created in WPForms into a tab within the user information in WooCommerce. I can create the new tab I want inside the profile and the corresponding labels where the information is supposed to be stored, but every time I fill out the form, the data is not being saved.
The code I'm using is as follows:
PHP to retrieve the data:
// Hook para ejecutar cuando se envíe el formulario
function guardar_datos_wpforms($entry, $form_data) {
    $form_id = 123; // Cambia esto al ID de tu formulario WPForms
    
    if ($form_data['id'] == $form_id) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        if ($user_id) {
            // Obtener datos del formulario
            $fields = $entry['fields']; // Campos del formulario
            
            $nombre_mascota = isset($fields['1']) ? sanitize_text_field($fields['1']['value']) : '';
            
            // Registrar datos para depuración
            error_log('Formulario ID: ' . $form_id);
            error_log('Usuario ID: ' . $user_id);
            error_log('Nombre de la Mascota: ' . $nombre_mascota);
            
            // Guardar en el perfil del usuario
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'nombre_mascota', $nombre_mascota);
        }
    }
}
add_action('wpforms_process_complete', 'guardar_datos_wpforms', 10, 2);


PHP to save the data:
// Guardar la información de la pestaña 'Mascota'
function guardar_pestaña_mascota($user_id) {
    // Verificar que el usuario tiene permisos para editar su propio perfil
    if (!current_user_can('edit_user', $user_id)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Verificar que los datos están presentes en $_POST
    if (isset($_POST['nombre_mascota'])) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'nombre_mascota', sanitize_text_field($_POST['nombre_mascota']));
    }

}
add_action('personal_options_update', 'guardar_pestaña_mascota');
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'guardar_pestaña_mascota');

PHP to create the tab and store the information there:
// Añadir la pestaña 'Mascota' al perfil del usuario
function agregar_pestaña_mascota($user) {
    ?>
    <h3><?php _e('Información de la Mascota', 'twentytwentyfour'); ?></h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="nombre_mascota"><?php _e('Nombre del Perro'); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="nombre_mascota" id="nombre_mascota" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_author_meta('nombre_mascota', $user->ID)); ?>" class="regular-text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
add_action('show_user_profile', 'agregar_pestaña_mascota');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'agregar_pestaña_mascota');


I'm using WPForms and the ID it generates in the builder.

You are accessing the $entry array the wrong way. ['fields'] you will find under $form_data.
Replace
$nombre_mascota = isset($fields['1']) ? sanitize_text_field($fields['1']['value']) : '';

To this
$nombre_mascota = isset($entry['1']) ? sanitize_text_field($entry['1']['value']) : '';

Final
// Hook para ejecutar cuando se envíe el formulario
function guardar_datos_wpforms($entry, $form_data) {
    $form_id = 123; // Cambia esto al ID de tu formulario WPForms
    
    if ($form_data['id'] == $form_id) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        if ($user_id) {
            // Obtener datos del formulario
            $fields = $entry['fields']; // Campos del formulario
            
            $nombre_mascota = isset($entry['1']) ? sanitize_text_field($entry['1']['value']) : '';
            
            // Registrar datos para depuración
            error_log('Formulario ID: ' . $form_id);
            error_log('Usuario ID: ' . $user_id);
            error_log('Nombre de la Mascota: ' . $nombre_mascota);
            
            // Guardar en el perfil del usuario
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'nombre_mascota', $nombre_mascota);
        }
    }
}
add_action('wpforms_process_complete', 'guardar_datos_wpforms', 10, 2);

